# Specify namespace when creating kubernetes PV/PVC with Terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

I am trying to create PV/PVC on a `kubernetes` GKE cluster using `Terraform`

However the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/r/persistent_volume.html) does not [mention](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/r/persistent_volume_claim.html) how can one specify the `namespace` that these resources should be created in.

I have tried adding it both in the `spec` and the `metadata` section but I get an error message:

```
resource "kubernetes_persistent_volume" "jenkins-persistent-volume" {
  metadata {
    name = "${var.kubernetes_persistent_volume_metadata_name}"
    # tried placing it here -->> namespace = "${var.kubernetes_jenkins_namespace}"

  }
  spec {
    # tried placing it here -->> namespace = "${var.kubernetes_jenkins_namespace}"
    capacity = {
      storage = "${var.kubernetes_persistent_volume_spec_capacity_storage}"
    }
    storage_class_name = "standard"
    access_modes = ["ReadWriteMany"]
    persistent_volume_source {
      gce_persistent_disk {
        fs_type = "ext4"
        pd_name = "${google_compute_disk.jenkins-disk.name}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> Error: module.jenkins.kubernetes_persistent_volume.jenkins-persistent-volume: spec.0: invalid or unknown key: namespace

Where such a configuration be placed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Persistent volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) are cluster-global objects and do not live in specific namespaces.  ("It is a resource in the cluster just like a node is a cluster resource.")  Correspondingly you can't include a namespace name anywhere on a `kubernetes_persistent_volume` resource.

If you're running in a cloud environment (and here your PV is creating a Google storage volume) its typical to only create a persistent volume claim, and let the cluster allocate the underlying volume for you.  PVCs *are* namespace-scoped, and the Terraform [`kubernetes_persistent_volume_claim` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/r/persistent_volume_claim.html) explicitly [documents](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/r/persistent_volume_claim.html#namespace) that you can include a `namespace` in the `metadata` block.